# Self Driving Algorithm

Tags: opencv

I'm currently trying to make a self-driving car algorithm that will work with a racing game using open cv and lane detection.

My current algorithm is to take the difference between the the x-component of the lanes to the centre (a certain y distance away from the car) and to adjust the direction based on the difference. This works well with oval tracks. However, it's really unstable with sharp turns.

Does anyone have any suggestions of a better way to implement a self-driving algorithm?

Thanks

Comment: Your algorithm needs to turn faster for the sharper corners.  Real humans anticipate; your algorithm should "look forward," not just to the left or right.

Comment: You should use a control algorithm like PID. Your current algorithm is working like "right-left logic".